# Sequence of Events - Basic understanding

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have an idea of the meaning of a sample space, and the events included in a sigma algebra. However, I am stuck in the definition of a *sequence* of events.

My difficulty is in the fact that in a sequence order matters, whereas in a set it does not. An event is a set of outcomes, and as such, it is not supposed to be ordered.

One way to look at it is to just to think of the real line, and Borel sets defined as open intervals, such that the intervals $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$, for example, would correspond to the sequence of events $\{(1,2)\},\{(2,3)\},\{(3,4)\}$. But I don't think this is the idea, and not all sets in a sigma algebra are defined on the real line.

Perhaps the idea is of nested "Russian dolls", whereby $E_1\subseteq E_2 \subseteq E_3 \subseteq E_4,\cdots$

[image]

So what is the definition and some valid examples of sequences of events (or sets)?

Comment: Each set of outcomes, that is, each event, is an unordered set. A sequence of events is, well, a sequence, that is a map $n\mapsto A_n$ from $\mathbb N$ to the set $\mathcal F$ of events. Thus it can be identified with $(A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots)$, that is, with an ordered set of events.

Comment: Are you trying to get through to me that any mapping from the natural numbers to whatever collection of sets will do? That it is up to us to order them in whichever way we want?

Comment: Simply that "sequences" are inherently ordered, that is, the sequences $(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$ and $(2,1,3,4,\ldots)$ are not the same.

Comment: Right, but the assignment is not a property of the sets, but our imposed order from the outside?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Thanks. How can I reward you?

Comment: You just did... :-) More seriously, you could post an answer below explaining what you understood, and even accept it after a while and if users seem to agree its mathematical content is adequate,

Answer (score -1):

If you have any sample space, label it $\Omega$, then the Cartesian product $\Omega{\times}\Omega$ is also a sample space; and so in any $n$-order Cartesian exponential, $\Omega^n$ (for any positive integer $n$).

Any event drawn from the sample space $\Omega^n$ is also a *sequence* of $n$ events drawn from the sample space $\Omega$.

---

For instance, take the sample space of a fair coin toss, $\Omega=\{{\small\rm H},{\small\rm T}\}$.   A sequence of the events resulting from two fair coin tosses, such as $({\small\rm T},{\small\rm H})$ , is a event from the sample space of $\{({\small\rm H},{\small\rm H}),({\small\rm H},{\small\rm T}),({\small\rm T},{\small\rm H}),({\small\rm T},{\small\rm T})\}$; which is $\{{\small\rm H},{\small\rm T}\}^2$

Comment: "Any event drawn from the sample space $\Omega^n$ is also a *sequence* of $n$ events drawn from the sample space $\Omega$." No. You might mean that any sample drawn from the sample space $\Omega^n$ is also a *sequence* of $n$ samples drawn from the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: My understanding: If $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ then the samples are $H$ and $T$. The events are the 4 elements of $\wp(\Omega)$. In that line: $(T,H)$ is not an event of $\Omega^2$ but $\{(T,H)\}$ is. I think it is important here to be strict. This because the title of the question speaks of "Basic understanding".

Comment: Can I then conclude that the idea of order in a sequence of events is as... thinking of a word... "random" (?), as if we were to list all the points in a 3D  Cartesian coordinate system: $(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),\cdots$, but possibly without any trace of arithmetic series in the enumeration depending on the nature of the sample space?